# If I want to get a list of all products that a certain customer has purchased, how would I express this relationship using RESTful conventions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest

So if I wanted to get a list of all products, I'd use an HTTP GET request on /products, and if I wanted to get a specific product, I'd use an HTTP GET request on /products/:id, but what is the convention if I want to get a list of all of the products that a certain customer has purchased? Using a nested resource in this case wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go a couple of ways here, but the noun here is really a "purchase"

So `/purchases` could be your list of purchases.

`/purchases/1` and `/purchases/2` are the first and second purchases you created.

"transactions" would work just as well here.